# How to prevent remote users from shutting down/rebooting the Windows?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, shutdown

Is it there any way to prevent remote users from shutting down/rebooting the Windows.

follows these steps:
[image]
Unfortunately, I cannot disable remote access to my computer. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

Open `secpol.msc` from the Run menu to open "Local Security Policy", from there navigate to `Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment`. In that subfolder find the option for `Shut down the system` and add the group named `Console Logon` to the list then remove the other groups from the list.

This will have the affect of only allowing people who can physically log on to the console session to be able to shutdown the computer.